# What is the meaning of cont in C++/C?

Tags: c

I was recently looking at this page:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Iteration_statements and there was this snippet of code:

```c
e1;
while (e2)
{
    s;
cont:
    e3;
}
```

which is apparenly equivalent to:

```c
for (e1; e2; e3)
    s;
```

But I've never seen the "cont:" that is used here, and searching the web does not give out anything useful. What does it really mean and when can you use it?

Comment: It's a label used with goto.

Comment: @Shawn What is goto? What is this actually doing?

Comment: There are not fully equivalent.  Consider `s` with a `continue`.

Answer (score 3):

The `cont:` is a label, which would be used by `goto`. 
I believe it appears in this snippet to explain the difference between `for` and `while`: when you use `continue` in a `for` loop, it is equivalent to using `goto cont` in a `while` loop, not `continue`.

Please check the next paragraph, **Jump statements**. The label `cont:` was put to use there.

> A `continue` statement may appear only within an iteration statement and
>   causes control to pass to the loop-continuation portion of the
>   innermost enclosing iteration statement. That is, within each of the
>   statements

```
 while (expression) {
     /* ... */
     cont: ; }

 do {
     /* ... */
     cont: ; } while (expression);

 for (expr1; expr2; expr3) {
      /* ... */
      cont: ; }
```

> a `continue` not contained within a nested iteration statement is the same as `goto cont`.

Comment: what is "loop-continuation portion" in "causes control to pass to the loop-continuation portion"? What is it being passed to? Is pass being used in the same sense of "passing an argument"?